# Angular 6 Quiz Form: Bind and Save data between pages

Tags: html, angular, forms, typescript

My project contains 4 components: Course-List, Course-Detail, Course-Play, Course Quiz, and the scheme is like that: [image]
The data is pass like that: every course have array of segment and every segments have array of questions. All the data I get from a backend server (Ruby on Rails API project) and it pass correctly.

This is the interfaces of each data structure:

```js
export interface ICourse {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  autor: string;
  segments: ISegment[];
}

export interface ISegment {
  id: number;
  unit_id: number;
  unit_title: string;
  name: string;
  type: string;
  data: string;
  questions: IQuestion[];
}

export interface IQuestion {
  id: number;
  question: string;
  answer1: string;
  answer2: string;
  answer3: string;
  answer4: string;
  correct: number;
}
```

I'm having a problem with course-quiz component. 
**This is how the quiz looks:** [image]

**Problems:**

1. When click submit and next the data's not saving
2. I want to add option of coloring the correct answer and user answer after press submit
3. I want that when all questions are answered that new page show instead (not working probably because the first)

[This is the project in stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wc6zeu). The project not working because stackblitz isn't working with sass. I'll add relevant code also here:

**app-routing.module.ts**

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { CourseListComponent } from './courses/course-list/course-list.component';
import { CourseDetailComponent } from './courses/course-detail/course-detail.component';
import { CoursePlayComponent } from './courses/course-play/course-play.component';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './page-not-found/page-not-found.component';
import { CourseQuizComponent } from './courses/course-play/course-quiz/course-quiz.component';


// Routing array - set routes to each html page
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/courses', pathMatch: 'full', runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always' },
  { path: 'courses', component: CourseListComponent,  pathMatch: 'full', runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always' },
  { path: 'courses/:id', component: CourseDetailComponent, pathMatch: 'full', runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always' },
  { path: 'courses/:id/segments/:id', component: CoursePlayComponent, pathMatch: 'full', runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always',
    children: [{ path: 'questions/:id', component: CourseQuizComponent }]
  },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent, pathMatch: 'full', runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always' }];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload' })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule {  }
```

**course-play.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router, Routes, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
import { MatSidenavModule } from '@angular/material/sidenav';
import { LocalStorage } from '@ngx-pwa/local-storage';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { ICourse } from '../course';
import { ISegment } from '../course';
import { CourseService } from '../course.service';


// Couse-play decorator
@Component({
  selector: 'lg-course-play-course-play',
  templateUrl: './course-play.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./course-play.component.sass']
})

export class CoursePlayComponent implements OnInit {
  errorMessage: string;
  course: ICourse;
  courseId: number;
  public currentSegment: ISegment;
  public showChildren: boolean = false;

  constructor(private courseService: CourseService,
      private route: ActivatedRoute,
      private router: Router,
      public sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }


    ngOnInit() {
        // save this course id from course-detail and get http request from the service
        this.courseId = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("courseId"))
        this.getCourse(this.courseId);
      }

      // Get course detail by id
      getCourse(id: number) {
        this.courseService.getCourse(this.courseId).subscribe(
          course => {
              this.course = course;

              // get the current segment id to use it on the html file
              const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
              this.getCurrentSegment(id);
          },
          error  => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
        }

      // search in course single segment by id and save it in currentSegment
      // to use it in the html file
      getCurrentSegment(id: number){
          this.currentSegment = this.course.segments.find(d => d.id === id);
      }

      changeShowChildren() {
        this.showChildren = !this.showChildren;
      }
}
```

**course-play.component.html**

```html
  <div class="row content" *ngIf="course">
    <!-- Side nav-bar -->
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <!-- Image Logo -->
      <div id="head_sidebar">
        <img src="./assets/images/lg-white.png" class="d-inline-block align-top logo" alt="" routerLink="/courses" style="outline: none">
        <h3>{{course.title}}</h3>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-12 sidenav">
        <!-- Menu elemets -->
        <div class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" *ngFor="let unit of course.segments | groupBy: 'unit_title'; let i = index">
          <h6 class="course_play_title">Unit {{ i+1 }}: {{ unit.key }} </h6>
          <ul>
            <li class="course_play_item"  *ngFor="let lesson of unit.value">
              <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/courses', course.id, 'segments', lesson.id]" (click)=getCurrentSegment(lesson.id)>{{lesson.name}}</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Body -->
    <div class="col-md-9 no-gutters" *ngIf="currentSegment">
      <!-- Video Div -->
      <div class="col-md-12 course_play_body text-center" *ngIf="currentSegment.segment_type === 'Video'">
        <h1>{{currentSegment.name}}</h1>
        <p class="small-text" *ngIf="course.segments?.length > 0">lesson {{currentSegment.id}} of {{course.segments?.length}}</p>
        <hr>
        <iframe frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true" [src]='currentSegment.data | safe'></iframe>
        <button type="button" class="prev btn btn-primary btn-lg" *ngIf="currentSegment.id > 1" [routerLink]="['/courses', course.id, 'segments', currentSegment.id-1]" (click)=getCurrentSegment(currentSegment.id-1)>Previous</button>
        <button type="button" class="next btn btn-primary btn-lg" *ngIf="currentSegment.id < course.segments?.length" [routerLink]="['/courses', course.id, 'segments', currentSegment.id+1]" (click)=getCurrentSegment(currentSegment.id+1)>Next</button>
      </div>

      <!-- Quiz Div -->
      <div class="col-md-12 course_play_body" *ngIf="currentSegment.segment_type === 'Quiz'">
        <div class="col-md-12 course_play_body text-center" *ngIf="showChildren === false">
          <h1>{{currentSegment.name}}</h1>
          <p class="text-left"> Now that you've finished this unit, It's time to take a short quiz and see what you learned so far!
              You'll need to choose one out of four answers which you think is correct.
              After you've finished the quiz, you'll get your grade. feel free to re-take this quiz as much as you like.
              Good Luck!
            </p>
            <p class="text-left big-text"> {{currentSegment.questions.length}} questions </p>
            <a (click) = "showChildren = true"><h4>Start Quiz</h4></a>

            <button style="margin-top: 30%" type="button" class="prev btn btn-primary btn-lg" *ngIf="currentSegment.id > 1" [routerLink]="['/courses', course.id, 'segments', currentSegment.id-1]" (click)=getCurrentSegment(currentSegment.id-1)>Previous</button>
            <button style="margin-top: 30%" type="button" class="next btn btn-primary btn-lg" *ngIf="currentSegment.id < course.segments?.length" [routerLink]="['/courses', course.id, 'segments', currentSegment.id+1]" (click)=getCurrentSegment(currentSegment.id+1)>Next</button>
          </div>
            <quiz-course *ngIf="showChildren === true" [items]="currentSegment?.questions"></quiz-course>
        </div>

  </div>
```

**course-quiz.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router, Routes, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';

import { ICourse } from '../../course';
import { ISegment } from '../../course';
import { IQuestion } from '../../course';
import { CourseService } from '../../course.service';
import { PagerService } from '../../pager.service';

import * as _ from 'underscore';

@Component({
  selector: 'quiz-course',
  templateUrl: './course-quiz.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./course-quiz.component.sass']
})

export class CourseQuizComponent implements OnInit {

  // the data I get from course-play component
  @Input() items: IQuestion[];

  // variables for pagination
  pagedItems: IQuestion[];
  pager: any = {};

  public userAnswers = ['0', '0', '0', '0'];    // array of user answers
  public index: int;                            // index of userAnswers
  public checkedAnswer: int;                    // the checked answer the user choose
  public correctAnswer: boolean = false;        // true if his answer correct, else false
  public sum: int;                              // sum of the questions answered. needed to check if user finished quiz

  constructor(private courseService: CourseService,
      private route: ActivatedRoute,
      private router: Router,
      private pagerService: PagerService) {  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.setPage(1);
    this.checkedAnswer = 0;
    this.index = 0;
    this.sum = 0;
  }

  // change pages
  setPage(page: number) {
    if (page < 1 || page > this.pager.totalPages) {
        return;
    }

    // get pager object from service
    this.pager = this.pagerService.getPager(this.items.length, page);

    // get current page of items
    this.pagedItems = this.items.slice(this.pager.startIndex, this.pager.endIndex + 1);
  }

  isChecked(value){
    this.checkedAnswer = value;
  }

  // get value of the checked answer, check if it's correct and save it to the answer array
  submitAnswer(correct) {

    // if the user answer all the questions, go to finished page
    if (sum == this.items.length) {
    
    }

    if (this.checkedAnswer == 0) {
      // do something to notify user that an answer need to be checked
    }

    else if (this.checkedAnswer == correct) {
      this.correctAnswer = true;
      this.userAnswers[this.index] = "correct";
    }

    else {
      this.correctAnswer = false;
      this.userAnswers[this.index] = "incorrect";
    }

    this.index = this.index + 1;
    this.sum = this.sum + 1;
  }

}
```

**course-quiz.component.html**

```html
  <div class="container" *ngIf="sum < 4">
      <div class="text-left quiz-body" *ngFor="let item of pagedItems">
        <form>
          <!-- items being paged -->
          <h3>Question {{item.id}}/{{items.length}}</h3>
          <h6>Question {{item.question}}</h6>
          <ul class="items">
            <li><input type="radio" id="answer1" name="answer" value="1" (click)="isChecked(1)"><label for="answer1">1. {{item.answer1}}</label></li>
            <li><input type="radio" id="answer1" name="answer" value="2" (click)="isChecked(2)"><label for="answer2">2. {{item.answer2}}</label></li>
            <li><input type="radio" id="answer1" name="answer" value="3" (click)="isChecked(3)"><label for="answer3">3. {{item.answer3}}</label></li>
            <li><input type="radio" id="answer1" name="answer" value="4" (click)="isChecked(4)"><label for="answer4">4. {{item.answer4}}</label></li>
          </ul>

          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2" (click)="submitAnswer(item.correct)">Submit</button>
          <!-- Submit Buttom -->


          <!-- pager -->
          <ul *ngIf="pager.pages && pager.pages.length" class="pagination">
              <li class="page-item" [ngClass]="{disabled:pager.currentPage === 1}">
                  <a class="page-link" (click)="setPage(1)">First</a>
              </li>
              <li class="page-item" [ngClass]="{disabled:pager.currentPage === 1}">
                  <a class="page-link" (click)="setPage(pager.currentPage - 1)">Previous</a>
              </li>
              <li class="page-item" *ngFor="let page of pager.pages" [ngClass]="{active:pager.currentPage === page}">
                  <a class="page-link" (click)="setPage(page)">{{page}}</a>
              </li>
              <li class="page-item" [ngClass]="{disabled:pager.currentPage === pager.totalPages}">
                  <a class="page-link" (click)="setPage(pager.currentPage + 1)">Next</a>
              </li>
              <li class="page-item" [ngClass]="{disabled:pager.currentPage === pager.totalPages}">
                  <a class="page-link" (click)="setPage(pager.totalPages)">Last</a>
              </li>
          </ul>
        </form>
      </div>
</div>


<!-- If the user finished the quiz, this div will displaying instead -->
<div class="container" *ngIf="sum == 4">
  <h3> You have just finished the quiz! </h3>
</div>
```

Comment: First of all you have to think about your pages. What you can do each page is tigger a resultboolean which show the quest or the result page. Cause when you hit previous or first you not want to show the question again but the results. 
Second what you can do is make a shared services and update your answers towards there. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-shared-service as an example. Third I'm not going to spend hours on making this code, sorry

Comment: service is good when working with multiple components but I only have one who works on this quiz. is this really efficiant if I have only one component? and I don't understand what yo mean by trigger resultboolean, I think I did it but it didn't save the data

Comment: Small example this can be done in an array [{name: 'Question1', values: [value1,value2]}, {name: 'Question2', values: [value1,value2]}]. Now what you can do is an *ngFor="question of questions; let index = i" and underneat an *ngIf="selectedQuest === i" in your component this.selectedQuest = 0 to start with. And then if you sumbit you make a function addAnswer(_index :number, _answer: string) { this.questions[_index].answer = _answer } now in you code you check if answer is not undefined and if the selectedQuest is index then show answer otherwise show quest. Hope this helps or give you a idea